# requests.content works normally but saves corrupt pdf file when used inside app.route flask

Tags: python, pdf, routes, python-requests, http-post

I am trying to download a pdf from the link :

```
https://ptenantectdtest.blob.core.windows.net/documentcontainer/fae488ce-514d-4367-be48-610b19193e10?sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=It1gKsb%2BHmQwjqxAprbAROySOKAdd2qyFnW%2FoBi0uM0%3D&st=2019-07-18T18%3A20%3A05Z&se=2019-07-19T18%3A30%3A05Z&sp=r&rscd=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%20%228d4508bf-453e-45fd-8457-8fd158152ba7.pdf%22
```

When I use requests.content inside a python function, it works well and downloads the pdf but when I use the same inside app.route, it saves a corrupt pdf file.

Code for normal python function using requests:

```
def download_url(url):
  r = requests.get(url)
  with open('D:/file_.pdf', 'wb') as f:
      f.write(r.content)
  categories = convert('D:/file_.pdf')
  return categories
```

Code for downloading from app.route:

```
import requests
import ectd
from ectd import convert
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)   
class ectdtext(Resource):
   def get(self, result):
       return {'data': ectd.convert(result)}



@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def get_dir(path):
   r = requests.get(path)
   with open('D:/3file_.pdf', 'wb') as f:
      f.write(r.content)
   categories = convert('D:/3file_.pdf')
   return categories 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: did you find a response to this, am facing similar issue.